# Jukebox Software/Distro

Tags: software-recommendation, touchscreen, music

I've seen a couple older threads that don't provide any answers still in active production so I thought I would ask again.  I am looking for a jukebox I can install on ubuntu, or I would even take one that's it own debian based bundle.  I am looking for the below features:

- Spotify connectivity (locked to a selected playlist)
- The ability for users to add nonexplicit material to the playlist
- Allow users to queue songs
- Do not allow users to skip current songs or remove them from playlist
- Jukebox interface/webpage that can be accessed from a central touchscreen device
- Web Interface
- A rating system to "smart shuffle" the playlist playing lower-rated songs less often
- Ability to output from the server utilizing 3.5mm

I would appreciate any help or insight if someone else has tried doing this already.  Thank you!

Comment: **To close voters:** This question asks for a software with very specific features. It's not opinion-based and shouldn't be closed.